# Converting MSaccess colors to RGB in VBA

Tags: vba, colors, powerpoint

I'm designing a macro to check all the shapes, charts and smart art on a given PowerPoint slide and print it's font colour and style.

The line that is (indirectly) giving me problems is

```
MsgBox .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB
```

The colour is outputted, but it is giving the MSaccess colour which is not as useful as the RGB colour. For example, a white block of text would be displayed as "16777215", whereas I would like to see "255,255,255"

I've indicated in the line that I want .color.rgb but this doesn't seem to make a difference.

I'd appreciate any help very much! Thank you!

Comment: Google is your friend.  Ask it for help with e.g. RGB LONG to R G B

Answer (score 0):

You can convert this "colorInt" to RGB using something like

```
B = floor(colorInt / (256*256))
G = floor((colorInt - B*256*256)/256)
R = colorInt - B*256*256 - G*256
```

Answer (score 0):

To format an RGB color with Excel:

```
Const color = vbMagenta

Dim r&, g&, b&
r = color And 255
g = color \ 256 And 255
b = color \ 65536
Debug.Print Format(r * 1000000 + g * 1000& + b, "000,000,000")
```